# Is a graph of the function connected?

Tags: general-topology

It's been a while since I studied and I've forgotten a lot of topology. Here is my problem: Is a graph of the following function connected?

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\[2ex]
-x, & x\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ and $V$ be the disjoint open sets in ${\mathbb R}^2$

$$U = \{(x, y): y < x - 2\} \qquad V = \{(x, y): y > x - 2\}$$

Then $U \cup V$ contains the graph $G$ of $f$, and $G$ contains the points
$(1, 1) \in V$ and $(\pi, -\pi)\in U$. Hence $G$ is not connected.

In order to see that $(x, f(x))$ is always an element of $U\cup V$, note that this is false only if $f(x) = x - 2$, which implies that $f(x)\not = x$, hence $x\not \in {\mathbb Q}$, but then $f(x) = -x = x-2$, which implies $x = 1 \in {\mathbb Q}$, a contradiction.

Edit: One could easily prove that $G$ is in fact [totally disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space) by proving that any pair of points in $G$ can be separated this way by a straight line that does not intersect $G$: the lines having the equation $y = x - a$ with $a\in {\mathbb Q}^*$ or $y = -x + b$ with $b\in {\mathbb R}\setminus {\mathbb Q}$ can be used to separate any pair of points in $G$.

Comment: I assume that $G$ is equipped with the topology induced by that of ${\mathbb R}^2$. This means that $U\cap G$ and $V\cap G$ are disjoint open sets in $G$ which union is equal to $G$.